# fetch_array to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I'm still new to PDO. Need to know the replacement of this mysqli code to PDO.

```
public function validusername() {
    $conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'project');
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$this->username'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    return ($result->fetch_array()[0] == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Note: `$this->username` is a value which is from `$_POST['username']` from `public function ___contruct` in a single class. This mysqli will check if the username is exist in MySQL and will return true if any.

I tried to replace the codes with these:

```
public function validusername() {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=project', 'root', '');

    $result = $db->prepare('
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM users
        WHERE username = :username
    ');
    $result->execute(['username'=>$this->username]);
    $result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return ($result[0] == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php have you even tried it, to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: You're open for SQL injections.

Comment: @Daan you're out of topic. I know those and will secure them later. That's not the main problem

Comment: Secure your code before posting here, so someone won't mention it.

Comment: @Daan thanks for your advice but, as I know, PDO's prepare statement has already do its work, right?

Comment: @Daan It seems the OP is trying to replace the vulnarable code with code that uses a prepared statement so the OP is actually in the process of fixing the sql injection.

Comment: @jeroen I'm well aware of that, still it's worth mentioning for people who are going to read this topic.

Comment: Please try it with `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=project;charset=utf8', 'root', '', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);` a) do you get an error/exception now the error mode is set? b) charset=utf8  ...just guessing.

Comment: Are you sure you want to return true if it finds a result?

Comment: @Clayton the function's name is `validusername` -> yes/no, true/false - why not? Little bit misleading the name but ....

Comment: @VolkerK and why would pdo output error is any when it's in a function? the function will return true or false anyway, right?

Comment: Not with PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION; you either catch the exception or it will bubble up to the unhandled exception handler, see http://docs.php.net/exceptions

Comment: still return false. also, no error. what a weird situation

Comment: btw: what's your [error_reporting](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) level and how do you check for warnings/notices? Your original code with `$result=...fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and `return ($result[0]` should have raised an undefined index warning,

Comment: yes I do just after I turned on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: When you use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC the fields are returned only as `'fieldname'=>value`. So there is no $result[0]. Take a close look at Clayton's answer, esp. the `SELECT COUNT(\`uid\`) AS total` and `$result['total']` parts. You _could_ use PDO::FETCH_NUM though ....

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need to do is correctly reference the parameter in your parameter list

```
$result->execute(['username'=>$this->username]);
```

it should be

```
$result->execute([':username'=>$this->username]);
```

Notice the `:` in front of the parameter array key field was missing

You are also not using any error checking. I prefer to set PDO to throw exceptions but as you dont you can also test the result of each call and output the database error so you know more about whats wrong like this

```
public function validusername() {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=project', 'root', '');

    $result = $db->prepare('
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM users
        WHERE username = :username');
    if ( ! $result ) {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
        exit;
    }

    if ( ! $result->execute(['username'=>$this->username]) ) {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
        exit;
    }

    $result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return ($result[0] == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Additional tip:

It is normal to connect to the database only once per execution. You appear to be doing it for each method. It would be better to pass `$db` as a parameter or better still to hold the `$db` handle as a class property and set it as part of the constructor. Connection is quite a time consuming action.

Comment: I can't find a reference, but I am pretty sure that you can use both.

Comment: Maybe so, but all the pityfully poor documentation always uses the colon so its a good place to start

Comment: Still I have learned something already today, so thats a plus

Answer (score 2):

The main changes are:

1. Use a DSN when using PDO - the DSN will include the database, hostname or port (optional)
2. You define the fetch mode on the instance of the connection object.
3. You can easily bind your values to the query to prevent SQL injection
4. You create a statement with the prepare method then call execute on the variable returned from that.

Here is your code updated to reflect what is mentioned above:

```
public function validusername() {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=project;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
    // return all result sets as associative array
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`uid`) AS total FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $this->username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    return $row['total']==1;
}
```

And a quick way to bind a variable is to do this:

```
$stmt->execute([':username'=>$this->username]);
```

instead of this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $this->username);
$stmt->execute();
```

With bindParam you can set the param type for the third parameter (such as int or boolean).

Here is the documentation for PDO's statement object which provides a number of 
other examples for executing queries: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Recieved `Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object`. Any ideas?

Comment: I made a mistake, should be `$stmt->fetch()`, updated

Comment: `return $row['total']==1;`. what it should return? an array, int?

Comment: that returns a true or false given the condition. try this out `var_dump(1==2);` or `var_dump(2==2)` or `$example = 2==5;` .. it's just a boolean.

Comment: And, another example: `return $row['total']==1;` is equivalent to `return $row['total']==1 ? true : false;`

Comment: should i put `var_dump(1==2);` at the ouput page or at the function? also, thanks for telling me about that.

Comment: No you do not need to use it for anything, it's just for you test it and understand why I am using `return $row['total']==1;` just trying to make it clear that it will produce the same result for you.

Comment: after testing it ,it returns false on everything input

Comment: What is the purpose of your validusername method...?

Comment: validusername should return true if the username submitted from `$_POST['username']` is exist in MySQL table

Comment: it checks for the total of row for the username submitted to the database which MySQL should return 1 if any and 0 if not..

Comment: Also, the code in your original question changed.  There  are backticks in the COUNT(  ) in the query

Comment: if so, i would recieve `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '*' in 'field list''`

Comment: Right, I'm just pointing that out to make sure you weren't testing that one out.. please edit your post with whatever code you are testing.  Something is wrong but it is not clear. I tested my code and it worked for me so please post what you are testing with.

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM ``users`` WHERE username = 'kroulikhwan'` this would work. but with `*`, that woudn't work.. tested on phpmyadmin and sequel pro

Comment: sorry, i meant SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username = 'kroulikhwan'

Comment: What PHP code are you testing with? Please update your post with the PHP code you are using / testing with

Comment: I have to go dinner so won't be able to check back until later.

Comment: `SELECT Count(*)` is right anyway. `*` is not an identifier, so don't put it in backticks. `uid` on the other hand (as used in Clayton's code) _is_ an identifier, so it can be wrapped in backticks.